# Html file is not running in emulator

Tags: javascript, android, html

I've developed an html file with javascript code it mostly consists of.

That index.html is running on webview and action is performed, but when imported to android file then only UI is displaying but it is not performing action.

Here is my code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>BrainVita Game</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        .marble { width: 30px; height: 30px; border: 0px;position:inherit; top:0px; left:0px}
        .marbleHover { width: 30px;height:30px; border:2px; border-color:red}
        .divclass {border: 1px solid blue; width: 30px;height:30px; text-align:center;}
        .board-state-Hover {border: 2px solid red; width: 30px;height:30px;}
        .board-state-Active {border: 1px solid green; width: 30px;height:30px;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('jquery', '1.3.2');
            google.load('jqueryui', '1.7.2');
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function() 
        {

             $('#reset').click(function () 
            {
                DrawBoard();
            });
              DrawBoard();
        });


        function DrawBoard()
        {

            $('#Brainvita').empty();
            var gameBoard = "<table border='0' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='2'>";
            for(var rows = 0; rows < 7; rows++)
            {
                gameBoard+= "<tr>";
                for(var cols = 0; cols < 7; cols++)
                {
                    var imgId = " id = 'i" + rows + cols + "' ";
                    var divId = " id = 'd" + rows + cols + "' ";
                    var altValue = " alt = 'i" + rows + cols + "' ";
                    if(rows < 3 && cols > 1 && cols < 5)
                    {
                        gameBoard+= GetImageMarble(divId, imgId, altValue);
                    }
                    else if(rows > 1 && rows < 5)
                    {
                        if(rows == 3 && cols == 3)
                        {
                            gameBoard+= GetEmptyMarble(divId);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gameBoard+= GetImageMarble(divId, imgId, altValue);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(rows > 4 && cols > 1 && cols < 5)
                    {
                        gameBoard+= GetImageMarble(divId, imgId, altValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      gameBoard+= "<td></td>";
                    }
                }

                gameBoard+= "</tr>";
            }

            gameBoard += "</table>";
            $('#Brainvita').html(gameBoard);
            $("div[id^='d']").addClass('divclass');
            $('#Brainvita').removeClass('divclass');
            $("img[id^='i']").draggable({ containment: '#Brainvita', 
                   revert: 'invalid', 
                    tolerance: 'fit', 
                    snap: true,
                    snapMode: 'inner',
                    snapTolerance: 5});
            $("div[id^='d']").droppable({
                accept: function(event) {
                    var returnFlag = false;
                    if(event[0].nodeName == "IMG")
                    {
                        var destId = this.id;
                        var srcId = event[0].id;
                        var destNo = parseInt(destId.substring(1,3));
                        var srcNo = parseInt(srcId.substring(1,3));
                        var result = Math.abs(destNo - srcNo);
                        var removeNo = 0;

                        if($(this).length == 1 && result != 0)
                        {
                            switch(result)
                            {
                                case 2:

                                    removeNo = ((destNo - srcNo) > 0) ? destNo - 1 : destNo + 1; 
                                    break;    
                                case 20:

                                    removeNo = ((destNo - srcNo) > 0) ? destNo - 10 : destNo + 10; 
                                    break;
                            }

                            if((result == 2 || result == 20) && removeNo != 0)
                            {
                                var elementToBeRemoved = (removeNo < 10) ? "0" + removeNo : removeNo;

                                if($("#i" + elementToBeRemoved).length == 1 &&
                                $("#i" + ((destNo < 10) ? "0" + destNo : destNo)).length == 0)
                                {
                                    returnFlag = true;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return returnFlag;
                },
                hoverClass: 'board-state-Active',
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    var destId = this.id;                
                    var srcId = ui.helper.context.id; //event.srcElement.id;
                    var destNo = parseInt(destId.substring(1,3), 10);
                    var srcNo = parseInt(srcId.substring(1,3, 10));
                    var result = Math.abs(destNo - srcNo);
                    var removeNo = 0;


                    if($(this).length == 1 && result != 0)
                    {
                        switch(result)
                        {
                            case 2:
                                removeNo = ((destNo - srcNo) > 0) ? destNo - 1 : destNo + 1; 
                                break;    
                            case 20:
                                removeNo = ((destNo - srcNo) > 0) ? destNo - 10 : destNo + 10; 
                                break;
                        }

                        if((result == 2 || result == 20) && removeNo != 0)
                        {
                            ui.helper.context.id = "i" + ((destNo < 10) ? "0" + destNo : destNo);
                            ui.helper.context.alt = ui.helper.context.id;
                            var elementToBeRemoved = (removeNo < 10) ? "0" + removeNo : removeNo;

                            if($("#d" + elementToBeRemoved).length == 1)
                            {
                                $("#i" + elementToBeRemoved).remove();
                                $("#d" + elementToBeRemoved).empty();

                            }
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            });
        }

        function GetImageMarble(divId, imgId, altValue)
        {
            var imgTag = "<td align='center' valign='middle'><div ";
            imgTag = imgTag + divId;
            imgTag = imgTag + "><img ";
            imgTag = imgTag + altValue + imgId;
            imgTag = imgTag + " src='";
            imgTag = imgTag + "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_rTqG9Y-vJsM/S02FPRVxU2I/AAAAAAAACsA/Wa7Ne0AgY_w/s320/Red.PNG'";
            imgTag = imgTag + " class=\"marble\"></div></td>";
            return imgTag;
        }


        function GetEmptyMarble(divId)
        {
            return "<td><div " + divId + "></div></td>";
        }
        </script>

        <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="border: solid 1px green">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <button id="reset">
                        Reset Board</button><br />
                    <span id="messages"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="Brainvita">
                        Hello</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="Trace" style="display: none; width: 400px;">
            Trace Messages
        </div>
        <div id="adivSample" style="display: none; width: 100px">
            Where are you?
        </div>
        <div id="adebug" style="display: none; width: 100px">
            Debug Messages Here
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How could it be fixed?

Helping hands are appreciated.

Comment: what type of action is meant to take place?

Comment: Post code, what have you tried earlier?

Comment: post ur html code and what u try for that

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about an action, I'm assuming you are using javascript in your html file. To make the javascript work in your webview, you need to call `webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`